# Where is script table fixture reuse documented?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I read somewhere that if I start a table with `|script|` on a line by itself, without specifying a fixture name, FitNesse / Slim will reuse the fixture from the previous script table:

```
|script|my script table fixture|
|check|do something|ok|

Then something else happens, but later I want to keep using that fixture:

|script|
|check|do something else|ok|
```

But now I can't find where this is documented.  It's not mentioned on [the documentation page for script tables](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable).  Where is this feature actually described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is on the page you linked, although not too clearly:

> If there is no actor specified then the previous script table's actor on this test page will be used.